# Rails 3, Acts_As_Taggable_On: Destroying tags and related posts after limit has been reached (revised)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, acts-as-taggable-on

I am working with a tight limit on database space. So I am currently putting a hard limit on the amount of posts per tag in my database like this:

post.rb:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable
  after_create         :destroy_old_posts

  # ...

  protected
  def destroy_old_posts
    self.tag_list.each do |tag|
      posts = Post.tagged_with(tag, :order => 'updated_at DESC')
      posts[100..-1].each {|p| p.destroy } if posts.size >= 100
    end
  end
end
```

However, all posts belong to at least one tag through `acts_as_taggable_on`. How would I change this code to limit it to 100 tags maximum and 100 posts per tag instead of just 100 posts per tag? Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.5.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect my current findings. I figured out how to limit the amount of posts that belong to a tag, but I still haven't figured out how to remove older tags once the tag limit has been reached. I tried making a very similar method to the one above in the Tag model, but I'm not sure if it's even being called on the creation of a new post. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tags association is bi-directional (has_many :through) so `@post.tags.count` gets you the number of tags and `@tag.posts.count` gets the number of posts. A validation in the Post model. By adding a custom validation in the Post model, you can perform all your post and tag limiting before an individual object is committed to the database.

This approach might work for you. The idea is that a Post, before it is committed, validates its associated tags (though Taggings) and it also validates itself. Tag validates itself and by implication, will invalidate a Post if there are too many posts per tag. You may have to adjust the names for how you've set up your tagging.

```
class Post
  acts_as_taggable
  validates_associated :taggings
  validates :database_limits

  private
  def database_limits
    self.errors.add(:name, "too many tags") if self.tags.count > 100
  end
end

class Taggings
  validates_associated :tags
end

class Tag
  validates :database_limits

  private
  def database_limits
    self.errors.add(:name, "too many posts for this tag") if self.posts.count > 100
  end
end
```